# Android grouping settings layout

Tags: android, android-layout, telegram

I am trying to make something similar to the Telegram's app settings page. I can use PreferenceScreen but I actually dont need to store my data into shared preference. 
I also need them to be clustered just like Telegram. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Use cardview from support libraries. You will shadows be default for each card. The screenshot seems to be using two cardviews and listview inside it.

Comment: So its all custom made? I thought maybe there could be a something in Android for these sorts of layout cuz this is so common these days for settings page and they all look pretty much the same